# wordpress global $post returns null, works with other filters though

Tags: php, filter, wordpress

I am trying to save a post meta using post->ID, But the $post seems to be null and showing notice  - "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" (while accessing $post->ID)

Hence the add_filter doesn't seems to be working at all.

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', array($this, 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect')); // Goes in class constructor.


function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() {
    global $post;
    var_dump($post).die();      // this $post var is always null.
    return $this->woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_get_cartURL(); // The global $post declaration within this method doesn’t works too.
}
```

I also tried adding wp_post_resetdata() call before the global declaration, But no luck.

Any idea what's going wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar situation today, where the global `$post` wasn't available when it should've been. On closer examination, I found that every page request was returning true for `is_404()`, and the query for post 0 failed to return the data for the global `$post` object because of that.

Flushing permalinks did the trick for me (nothing fancy, I just re-saved them).

Comment: Thanks, flushing permalinks helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use woocommerce global variable like

```
global $woocommerce;
var_dump($woocommerce).die();
```

Comment: You are using woocommmerce action hook so it will work with it's own global variable

Comment: Ohh so is it possible to get current product ID based on it and save a product meta field, say a custom url ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the above code in an external PHP script? You may need to include wp_load.php

Comment: nope, It's a plug-in, the same works for other filters